# how to remove url query args in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

i'm new to WordPress development and in my WordPress plugin i have redirect to a Url which contains a query arg and i want to remove it before loading the page markup i use

```
$url = remove_query_arg('key', $url);
```

but it doesn't work

in my case i use it like this is it correct ?

```
    add_action( 'wp_logout', array( $this, function(){

        $redirect_url = home_url( 'my-login?logged_out=true' );
        wp_safe_redirect( $redirect_url );
        remove_query_arg('logged_out');

        exit;

    }));
```

Comment: it has a default value 'false'

Comment: Did you manage to solve it?